# How can I change the size of my SD card partition on os x 10.6.8 using gparted or disk utility?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, partitioning, sd-card

I"m running OS X 10.6.8 and I would like to use gparted to resize a partition on my SD card by following instructions on this page:

http://mitchtech.net/easy-gui-install-re-partition-raspberry-pi-on-ubuntu/

However, it appears like gparted is suitable only for linux environment. I was wondering what alternatives do I have on os x to achieve increasing the size of the partition on my SD card?

Would appreciate all / any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that Raspbian Wheezy operating system has an option under the "raspi-config" utility from command line.  All you need to do is select "Expand SD card" option and it does it for you.

So no need to use gparted at all.  Just boot up in your raspberry pi, pull up a terminal, and run "raspi-config". You will see a GUI that will give you options to select, one of them being expanding the SD card.